# Perl Webservice SSL Negotiation Failure

Tags: perl, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to call a web service using ssl. It gives following error:

> 500 SSL negotiation failed:

I searched forums and applied offered methods but none of them worked.

2 methods I applied are listed below:

1-) setting enviroment before call:

> $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;

2-) passing parameter ssl_opts => [ SSL_verify_mode => 0 ] to proxy:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite    
     -> on_action( .... )
     -> uri($uri)
     -> proxy($proxy, ssl_opts => [ SSL_verify_mode => 0 ])    
     -> ns("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","soapenv")
     -> ns("http://tempuri.org/","tem");
$soap->serializer()->encodingStyle(undef);
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 program.pl` and add the output to your question since it probably contains information which might be useful in debugging the problem. Apart from that ssl_opts should probably be a hash reference and not an array reference like in your case.

Comment: What happens if you connect to the given server with `openssl s_client -connect host:port`?

Comment: Also, the colon at the end of the error you quote leads me to believe there's more after that, isn't there?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich IO/Socket/SSL module is not installed at my company's server. I coud not see result. I do not have access to load it

Comment: @jcaron I know only wsdl adres starting with "https". But it is opened at browser.

Comment: @jcaron 500 SSL negotiation failed: 
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 12:19:42 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

SSL negotiation failed:  at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/Net/SSL.pm line 212.
; Connection reset by peer at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/Net/SSL.pm line 145.

Answer (score 3):

> ... Connection reset by peer at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/Net‌​/SSL.pm line 145

You are running a very old version of Perl (from 2004) together with an old version of the SSL libraries (i.e. Crypt::SSLeay instead of IO::Socket::SSL) and my guess is that this goes together with using a very old version of the OpenSSL libraries for TLS support. This combination means that there is no support for [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), no support for TLS 1.2 and no support for ECDHE ciphers. Many modern servers need at least one of these things supported. But `connection reset by peer` could also mean that some firewall is blocking connections or that there is no server listening on the endpoint you've specified. Or it could mean that the server is expecting you to authorize with a client certificate. Hard to tell but with a packet capture of the connection one might provide more information. And, if the URL is publicly accessible publishing it would help too in debugging the problem.